# Send form with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to submit those two forms shown below through an input button. Whereas the value on the button changes as expected when pressed nothing happens. When I try to add the f.submit an extra box appears under the button. So how can I do to link that button to the submit action? and also is there a better way of setting a value for the input to button that what I have done?

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value=" <% if current_user.following?(@user) %> Unfollow <%else%> Follow <%end%>">

<% unless current_user?(@user) %>

    <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>

      <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
         html: { method: :delete },
         remote: true) do |f| %>


      <% end %>

    <% else %>

      <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %></div>

      <% end %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your button isn't connected with the form in any way so that's why nothing happens.

I think the best way is to do it with some javascript.
Look for the onclick function.